# SQL Server 2019 how to give connection and permissions only to certain tables

Tags: sql-server

We are trying to allow users to make connections to a SQL Server and specific database and only a few tables with read permissions. Is this possible to allow a connection to the server, for instance through Power BI but only allow data returned from certain tables?

Comment: If you are asking about application-specific permissions, the short answer is no. If the reference to PowerBI was just an example, then the short answer is yes. You give logins access to the desired databases by creating a user and then you assign the desired permissions to that user (or assign that user to a role with the desired permissions).

Comment: is this a multi-tenant style solution, or is it all users of the PowerBI implementation should have acess to the same tables?

Answer (score 2):

PowerBI complicates things. The common workarounds include creating a separate schema and views within that schema that cover the accessible data tables. The view solution allows you to implement *quasi*-row-based security if needed. You then create a new user account that is bound to that schema. In PowerBI use that user account to access the database.

If your requirement doesn't need to go to the trouble of implementing views, in SQL Server it is possible to enable [table level security](https://chartio.com/learn/databases/grant-sql-server-table-permissions/) in a very similar fasion:

1. [Create a new Login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-login?view=sql-server-ver15)

   ```
   CREATE LOGIN powerBIuser   
       WITH PASSWORD = 'Baz1nga',  
       CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF;  
   GO
   ```
2. Grant access to the specified tables. The following query can be used to generate the script to explicity grant access to all tables. You can modify this to the table set you desire or could use the same format for individual tables:

   ```
   SELECT 'GRANT SELECT ON "' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '"."' + TABLE_NAME + '" TO       "powerBIuser"' 
   FROM information_schema.tables
   WHERE <insert your criteria here>
   ```

   This might return a result set like this:

   ```
   GRANT SELECT ON "dbo"."Customer" TO "powerBIuser"
   GRANT SELECT ON "dbo"."Employee" TO "powerBIuser"
   GRANT SELECT ON "dbo"."Genre" TO "powerBIuser"
   GRANT SELECT ON "dbo"."MediaType" TO "powerBIuser"
   GRANT SELECT ON "dbo"."Playlist" TO "powerBIuser"
   GRANT SELECT ON "dbo"."PlaylistTrack" TO "powerBIuser"
   GRANT SELECT ON "dbo"."Track" TO "powerBIuser"
   GRANT SELECT ON "dbo"."Album" TO "powerBIuser"
   GRANT SELECT ON "dbo"."Artist" TO "powerBIuser"
   ```

   You would then paste that result (or the elements you need) into the script pane of SSMS and execute it.
3. You then need to grant view permissions of the schema that these tables are bound to using the following:

   ```
   GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA :: dbo TO powerBIuser
   ```

The end result is that the `powerBIuser` account now *ONLY* has readonly or `SELECT` access to the tables mapped in the `GRANT` statements.

Finally, make sure to use this `powerBIuser` login as the saved credential in your powerBI SQL connector.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. :)